# SPARK ML, Naive Bayes classifier: high probability prediction for one class

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, classification, naivebayes, apache-spark-ml

I am using Spark ML to optimise a Naive Bayes multi-class classifier.

I have about 300 categories and I am classifying text documents.
The training set is balanced enough and there is about 300 training examples for each category.

All looks good and the classifier is working with acceptable precision on unseen documents. But what I am noticing that when classifying a new document, very often, the classifier assigns a high probability to one of the categories (the prediction probability is almost equal to 1), while the other categories receive very low probabilities (close to zero).

What are the possible reasons for this?

I would like to add that in SPARK ML there is something called "raw prediction" and when I look at it, I can see negative numbers but they have more or less comparable magnitude, so even the category with the high probability has comparable raw prediction score, but I am finding difficulties in interpreting this scores.

Comment: Logically, there is two types of unseen documents, on one hand, the ones that may infer unseen features which will be removed during the vector transformation before prediction, the other types which features belong already to the training set. So where do your unseen documents fit?

Comment: They fit in the second case eliasah.

Comment: Did you try to analyze words distributions on the whole training set and among each class?

Comment: I mean that I am using the same feature extraction method which is a HashingTF win 5000 as feature number.

Comment: No I didn't analyse the words distributions on the whole training set.

Comment: I'm afraid the number of features won't be enough. Maybe you'll need to analyze the words distribution first, knowing how many words there is, how many words per class, etc. It's a fastidious task unfortunately...

Comment: I tried it with 10,000 and 20,000 and found the same phenomenon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98133/discussion-between-eliasah-and-rami).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start with a very informal description of Naive Bayes classifier. If *C*  is a set of all classes and *d* is a document and *x<sub>i</sub>* are the features, Naive Bayes returns:

[image]

Since *P(d)* is the same for all classes we can simplify this to

[image]

where

[image]

Since we assume that features are conditionally independent (that is why it is naive) we can further simplify this (with Laplace correction to avoid zeros) to:

[image]

Problem with this expression is that in any non-trivial case it is numerically equal to zero. To avoid we use following property:

[image]

and replace initial condition with:

[image]

These are the values you get as the raw probabilities. Since each element is negative (logarithm of the value in (0, 1]) a whole expression has negative value as well. As you discovered by yourself these values [are further normalized](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.1/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/NaiveBayes.scala#L195) so the maximum value is equal to 1 and divided by the sum of the normalized values

It is important to note that while values you get are not strictly P(c|d) they preserve all important properties. The order and ratios are exactly (ignoring possible numerical issues) the same. If none other class gets prediction close to one it means that, given the evidence, it is a very strong prediction. So it is actually something you want to see.

Comment: Thanks @zero323 for the detailed answer. What I am noticing form my data is when we have large number of classes (e.g. in my case I have ~300) the sum of logs will lead into large negative values (e.g. -2081, -2092, ... etc.) and in this case I do know how we judge that the class who get a score of -2081 is much more likely than the class who get a score of -2092, the two scores look close enough for me. The normalization formula that you mentioned looks like designed to favour one class and penalise the rest in this case. As you suggest to me, I can implement my own normalization function.

Comment: There is also a huge difference between these values. exp(-2081) is roughly 1e-904 while exp(-2090) is close to 1e-908.

Comment: True, i tried to challenge your answer with an example and I couldn't. Thanks again